# Drawing line at different position of cursor

Tags: c#, cursor

[![enter image description here][10]][10]

I am drawing a line on picture in picture Box  and saving this picture in a folder(my computer). When i am trying to draw line, it draws line on different position rather than cursor position.

code---

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (paint)
        {
            Pen ppen = new Pen(Color.Black,1);

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            try
            {
                Gr =Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

                Gr.DrawLine(ppen,e.X,e.Y,Xold, Yold);

                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", 
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }

        Xold = e.X;
        Yold = e.Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to make sure that the PB doesn't **zoom** or **stretch** (or even **center**) the image.

Set `SizeMode = Normal` !

If you need a different `SizeMode` you will have to do a **little** math to calculate the image coodinates form the `image.Size` and the `PB.ClientSize`..

The calculation is simple but will be different for each `SizeMode`:

- For `Center` all you need is to add an offset to one of the coordinates.
- For `Zoom` You need to calculate the zoom factor and multiply it into both coordinates.
- And for `Stretch` you need to calculate the zoom factors of **both** dimensions independently and multiply it into **each respective** coordinate.

Btw: The way you draw lines by ading single lines will work only for simple Pens. Once you use semitransparent pens or fancy linecaps you will see artifacts at the junctions. If you need to avoid these, collect the points and use `DrawLines` (pl!) in the `Paint` event; then, upon `MouseUp` draw them into the Bitmap and then clear the list of points..